# How to get the homography matrix or get point in one camera to similar point in another camera with a different viewpoint

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, homography, object-tracking

I have 2 images and want to match co-ordinate in point 1 of camera 1 to similar point in camera 2.
I am not able to move ahead on this. I read about intrinsic, extrinsic parameters of camera, but haven't been able to get a grasp on it.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

I actually have the task to perform Multi Camera object tracking and plan it to do using geometrical approach, that is if the object is present in the overlapping area of both cameras, the object will be tracked using the same id.

Any help/ resources either on homography matrix or how to perform multi camera tracking would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I read about intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of camera but wasn't able to understand it very well. I have a fair idea of Intrinsic matrix though.
I also tried to do feature matching using light glue. Have the common points, but don't understand how do I link them using python

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html

Comment: a homography will not work ***in principle***. wrong tool. -- that problem requires full 3D information of the scene. a simple matrix cannot hold all that information. -- you should read up on multiple-view geometry.

Comment: You need a proper camera model for each picture and a 3D model of the scene. Then you can project the 2D point in one image to a 3D point on some object and then project that to a 2D point in the other image.  The 3D model can be just the ground plane if the point is on the ground.  If on an object above the ground, then you need the 3D model of the object to know the X,Y,Z point of the 3D point in World coordinates in your scene.

Comment: in the case of the scene being just a plane (ground plane), then sure, a homography would work, BUT the further you go away from the plane, the more distortion you'll get. that applies to humans, which are basically "sticking up" and away from the ground. the only good mapping will be for your feet because they're close to the ground.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the points. Will go through the pointers mentioned.